# from list to string and back to list

Tags: erlang

I have read a multiline file and converted it to a list with the following code:

```
Lines = string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Binary), "\n"),
```

I converted it to a string to do some work on it:

```
Flat = string:join(Lines, "\r\n"),
```

I finished working on the string and now I need to convert it back to a multiline list, I tried to repeat the first snippet shown above but that never worked, I tried string:join and that didnt work.. how do i convert it back to a list just like it used to be (although now modified)?

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on the modifications you made on the flattened string.
`string:tokens/2` will always explode a string using the separator you provide. So as long as your transformation preserves a specific string as separator between the individual substrings there should be no problem.

However, if you do something more elaborate and destructive in your transformation then the only way is to iterate on the string manually and construct the individual substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet above contains a call to `erlang:binary_to_list/1` which first converts a binary to a string (list) which you then split with the call to `string:tokens/2` which then join together with `string:join/2`. The result of doing the `tokens` then `join` as you have written it seems to be to convert it from a string containing lines separated by `\n` into one containing lines separated by `\r\n`. N.B. that this is a flat list of characters.

Is this what you intended?

What you should do now depends on what you mean by "I need to convert it back to a multiline list". Do you mean everything in a single list of characters (string), or in a nested list of lines where each line is a list of characters (string). I.e. if you ended up with

```
"here is line 1\r\nhere is line 2\r\nhere is line 3\r\n"
```

this already is a multiline line list, or do you mean

```
["here is line 1","here is line 2","here is line 3"]
```

Note that each "string" is itself a list of characters. What do you intend to do with it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You have your terms confused. A string in any language is a sequence of integer values corresponding to a human-readable characters. Whether the representation of the value is a binary or a list does not matter, both are technically strings because of the data they contain.

That being said, you converted a binary string to a list string in your first set of instructions. To convert a list into a binary, you can call `erlang:list_to_binary/1`, or `erlang:iolist_to_binary/1` if your list is not flat. For instance:

```
BinString = <<"this\nis\na\nstring">>.
ListString = "this\nis\na\nstring" = binary_to_list(BinString).
Words = ["this", "is", "a", "string"] = string:tokens(ListString, "\n").
<<"thisisastring">> = iolist_to_binary(Words).
Rejoined = "this\r\nis\r\na\r\nstring" = string:join(Words, "\r\n").
BinAgain = <<"this\r\nis\r\na\r\nstring">> = list_to_binary(Rejoined).
```

For your reference, the `string` module ***always*** expects a flat list (e.g., "this is a string", but not ["this", "is", "a", "string"]), except for `string:join`, which takes a list of flat strings.

Comment: Also, "this is a string" is just a special list syntax. It's exactly the same as: [$t, $h, $i, $s, $ , $i, $s, ...]. Similarly, an empty "string" is also an empty list, or: "" =:= [] (=:= is exactly equal to)